# Flutter simple calendar package

Tags: flutter

I need to construct a flutter basic calendar with no upcoming events; I simply want something like a habit tracker where I color some days based on certain conditions. The UI design of a calendar that I desire is shown in the image below ... if there is any package that can do that

[image]

Comment: Have you searched pub.dev? https://pub.dev/packages?q=calendar

Comment: yes, but all I found is the events calendars

Comment: This should work as you want. The UI is similar and you can highlight any day based on your logic.
https://pub.dev/packages/table_calendar

Comment: I tried to do that but I can't can you please provide a snapshot of code that can do that , That  will be a big help